# Spring Resttemplate with multiple Proxy host

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I have to call an api which is only accessible via bunch of proxy server(set of servers are deployed and anyone can be active at give point of time ) . I am using following code to set the proxy to rest template and then to pass it to OauthCLient manager,

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplate")
    RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
//                .customizers(restTemplate -> )
                .requestFactory(ServiceConfig::getSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)
                .additionalMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(new FormHttpMessageConverter(), new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter()))
                .errorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler())
                .interceptors((request, body, execution) -> {
                    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
//                    headers.add("Host", "apreview.com");
                    headers.forEach((key, value) -> log.info("header key: {} , header value: {}", key, value.get(0)));
                    return execution.execute(request, body);
                })
                .build();
    }

    @NotNull
    private static SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory getSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        Proxy proxy= new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8443));
        simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
        return simpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceAndManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService, RestOperations nnRestTemplate) {
        DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        tokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(nnRestTemplate);
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
                .builder()
                .clientCredentials(clientCredentialsGrantBuilder ->
                        clientCredentialsGrantBuilder.accessTokenResponseClient(
                                tokenResponseClient))
                .build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

My issue is that i need to check the active proxy servers and take any active server at that time to call the the target API. I couldnt find a way where i could set proxy configurations dynamically in Resttemplate. Could anyone help on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a right approach or not but I extended the Proxy class to handle the multiple proxy hosts at runtime. so whenever spring calls Proxy.address(), it will check for the live proxy address at that time and return that to spring.

```
public class AEDProxy extends Proxy {

public static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<InetSocketAddress>> RESOLVED_PROXY_ADDRESSES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public AEDProxy(Type type, SocketAddress sa) {
    super(type, sa);
}

@Override
public Type type() {
    return super.type();
}

@Override
public SocketAddress address() {
    return RESOLVED_PROXY_ADDRESSES.get("live");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}
```

}